# Viewing Images, PDFs and Video content without X?

Tags: terminal, multimedia

I was toying with the idea of going "terminal only" - completely ditching X, WM and DE. Apparently Richard Stallman does this (he doesn't run a graphical environment on his laptop).

But I was curious what he does when he wants to view Images or Video files, or nicely formatted pdfs. Is there some way to access such multimedia from the terminal without going the whole hog and booting up a GDE? I'm aware that there are terminal audio players such as cmus and they are lovely. Wondering if there is something similar for other forms of multimedia.

Comment: Video can be viewed with mpv/mplayer with `-vo sdl` or `-vo directfb`.

Comment: For images use fbida: https://github.com/fcarlier/fbida .

For any other file format, use a websearch engine like duckduckgo...

Comment: The keyword is [tag:framebuffer].